# git: publish from certain commit onward, keeping earlier history private, but provable

Tags: git, git-rebase

I've been hacking away on a library for quite some time and have a lot of commits in my `private` repository:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
```

Finally, I'm nearing completion of a first version, and want to publish it to a remote called `public` from `D` onward keeping `A..C` to myself, so `public` should afterwards look like this:

```
D -> E
```

On demand, I'd like to be able to prove how i arrived at `D` though (think of copyright claims, etc). As (at the moment) it's pretty much impossible to reverse-engineer the hashes of commits in the chain with times and changesets, i thought just keeping `D`'s parent pointer to `C` would be one of the genius advantages of git. Sadly i can't find a way to actually make this work.

So, how can i push `D -> E` to `public` making it a fully functional public repository with all the necessary objects included to checkout `D` or `E` and `D` still pointing to `C` as parent?

### What doesn't work:

#### push with range

```
git push public D..E:master
error: src refspec D..E does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to '<public>'
```

#### any form of squashing / history rewriting

As far as i know squashing `A..D` would introduce a new commit removing the parent pointer to `C` and thereby removing provability of the existence of `A..C`. (Simple example: say `C` reversed `B`, then you'd never be able to prove `B` was in there at some point.)

I could obviously manually note the hash of `C` in the description of the squash commit, but there already is a `parent` pointer field, why not use it?

Also in order to contribute further changes to public I'd have to rebase my private branches on top of this new squashed commit, which just seems as wrong...

#### push from local clone with limited depth

I thought i found a solution to this by first creating a local clone `local_public` with the desired depth before pushing that clone to `public` like this:

```
git clone --depth 2 file:///<abspath_private> local_public
```

With

```
git log --pretty=raw
```

I can verify that `local_public` only contains `D -> E` and that the commit, tree and parent hashes are the same, which is exactly what i want.

The problem is that when i try to push to an added `public` remote from `local_public` i get an error like this:

```
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (shallow update not allowed)
```

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: `On demand, I'd like to be able to prove how i arrived at D though` - this seems, sorry, shady and lame. What do you really want here?

Comment: @jörn-hees You apparently plan to keep working on this project, correct? If so, do you want to commit onto the stripped down history or onto the original history? So when making a new commit `F`, should your history look like `D -> E -> F` or do you want to keep `A` to `D` on your local working copy.

Comment: As this is your computer, there isn't any provability anyways.. One could fake sha1 ids as well as squashed commits.

Comment: @manojlds: I'm sorry if it sounds "shady and lame" to you that I'd like to know the options when it comes to being able to prove what i coded and when... notice how code ownership is very different across jurisdictions and into how much trouble projects can get for not being able to prove where code contributions came from. So all i want to do here is exactly what i asked.

Comment: @Uroc327: continuing work in either repository would be fine for me, as long as i don't have to constantly rebase things. Wrt. to the faking of sha1sums: it's still very hard to even find collisions and much much harder finding an alternative message for a given sha1sum. It would be ok for me to rely on that difficulty for now.

Comment: @JörnHees If you use the new, public repository as your new working directory you won't need to rebase anything. Althoug the sha1sums will then be different in both histories as you've already noted. Possibly you could use git `graft`s in combination with `git filter-branch` to fake some parent connection but I doubt it, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

**What you want is not possible**.

Commits in Git work like a linked list. Each commit has the ID of the parent commit (or null if root commit)... The ID of the parent commit is part of the identity of a commit.

To push D -> E to a repo, you will need to modify the parent of D, and that will cause the HASH of D to change, which in turn will require the hash of E to change as well (as E will have a new parent).

Comment: it's not entirely clear to me why i'd have to modify D to push it to a repository? I mean i can clearly `git clone --depth 2`, why isn't something similar possible at push time?

Comment: @JörnHees Not sure how I can re-word my answer above... When you try to push D -> E, Git looks for D's parent commit on the remote repository and can't find it - so it stops. To push D, you'd have to remove the relationship between D and C (parent) - that would work and you would be able to push. But changing the parent of D will invariably change the commit hash of D (and E)